# new server + domain: what to do with nameserver and dns?

Tags: dns, ubuntu-server, nameserver

I've set up a new server (Ubuntu server) (own IP) and now I need to redirect my domain to that server. How??

The domain provider (separate from server provider and separate from my isp) controls the DNS because I didn't change the nameserver. (Thats true right?? Nameserver points to same guys that sold me domain so that's where I configure the DNS?)

The DNS is directed to my new server's IP (2 A records I think, the rest is "@").

For some reason the domain still points to the old server. **I changed the DNS records well over 24 hours ago and now their TTL is 1 minute.**

**What am I missing here?** Does /etc/resolv have anything to do with it? **Before** I edited it, it was invalid (invalid syntax, according to `$ nslookup`).

I'm not a complete n00b =) but I am rather new to nameservers, DNS and (linux) networking.

Comment: The nameservers for the domain need to point to valid servers that hold your DNS records.  You would configure the DNS entries there.

Comment: Resolved! The problem was the nameservers. The domain registrar didn't save the correct nameservers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS records are normally served by a DNS server belonging to the company that sold you the domain. The NS records for your domain should point to their DNS nameservers. If your domain is example.com and the domain company's nameservers are at 198.51.100.1 and 198.51.100.2, your domain company will have set up these records (at the top-level nameservers)

`example.com IN NS 198.51.100.1`
`example.com IN NS 198.51.100.2`

If your new Ubuntu server has IP-address 203.0.113.0 and you wish to host www.example.com on it. You should use the domain company's control-panel (or other mechanism they provide) to set up DNS records at the domain company's DNS servers (198.51.100.1 and 198.51.100.2)

`www.example.com IN A 203.0.113.0`

On your Ubuntu server, resolv.conf should point at the DNS servers for the Internet Service Provider (ISP) that provides you with internet access (e.g. broadband) - This can be unrelated to any of the servers or businesses mentioned above.

---

Other sources of information:

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=48090

Comment: I only have A, MX and CNAME records in my DNS panel. No NS... * and www and vps01 (all A type) point to new server's IP... Can I test the resolve somehow? That the right DNS settings are used?

Comment: Do you change the nameservers to be used in the same DNS table?? The old server does have NS records (pointing to the 'old' server provider).

Comment: The NS records I mentioned are not at your domain company's nameservers, they are at the root nameservers as part of the "COM" zone. The NS records *delegate* management of the example.com to your domain company. Try `host -v -t NS example.com` (replacing example.com with your domain).

Comment: `$ host -t NS domain` returns the correct three nameservers... Is there something I have to (un)set (up) on the old server?? (That would be weird.)

Comment: Nameservers hold the DNS records (MX, PTR, A, CNAME, etc), they wont be a part of them, you'll change them somewhere in the settings for the domain from the registrar.

Comment: @Rudie: Now try `host -t A www.example.com`. where example.com is replaced by whatever your domain is named.

Comment: `host -t A domain` returns old server's IP address =( What am I missing?? (@MaQleod, that's what I thought.) It has nothing to do with settings on the linux machine itself?

Comment: BTW I am trying these cmds on the new server. (The old server is so old/crappy/weird that it doesn't know `$ host`)

Comment: @Rudie: Do you get the same answer for `host -t A example.com ns0.domaincompany.com` where ns0.domaincompany.com is the name or IP-address of your domain company's name servers.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, yes same results: old server's IP. The new DNS are ignored?

Comment: `host -t ...` says "Using nameserver: ..." and if I go to that IP (primary nameserver) I see the website of the old server's provider... That's weird isn't it? Because the new provider uses that nameserver...

Comment: Screw anonimity! Domain: hoblox.nl. Registar: TransIP (NS ns1.anony.nl). Old server: 89.18.176.168. New server: 178.18.95.56.

Comment: HUH if I do `host -t A hoblox.nl boguss.transip.nl` I get the right IP address as result!! Man why is internet so crazy difficult!?

Comment: @Rudie: I get the old address for hoblox.nl and www.hoblox.nl no matter what I try. I suggest you phone the help desk for TransIP.